# How to compile Bitcoin-Qt from GitHub source on Arch Linux?

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling, bitcoin-qt-setup

Here are the instructions I have created so far:

1. Install the necessary dependencies

   ```
   pacman -S boost boost-libs openssl db base-devel qrencode qt4 automoc4
   ```
2. Clone the GitHub repository:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
   cd bitcoin
   ```
3. Checkout the Git source to the latest release listed at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases:

   ```
   git checkout v0.8.5
   ```
4. Change to the source directory:

   ```
   cd src
   ```
5. Compile Bitcoin-Qt from source

   ```
   qmake-qt4 -makefile -Wall USE_QRCODE=1
   make
   ```

---

There are a ton of generic instructions spit out when I enter qmake-qt4 command and then upon entering the make command I am told:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

FYI, I am using the PKGBUILD file as a guideline for creating the above instructions.

Answer (score 5):

Since the build system has moved to [Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system), the method for building Bitcoin-Qt is a bit different.

```
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git bitcoin
cd bitcoin
git checkout v0.8.5
./autogen.sh 
./configure --with-qt
make -j8
```

Comment: exactly! this is how you do it

Comment: Will this method work on Ubuntu 14.04 too?